# Using the sh Python module, avoid exception logging when killing a background process

Tags: python

The following Python:

```
p=sh.sleep(100, _bg=True)

try:
  p.kill()
except sh.SignalException_SIGKILL:
  print('foo')
```

Gives me:

```
>>> Exception in thread background thread for pid 14892:
Traceback (most recent call last):

<blah blah blag, long stack trace elided> 

sh.SignalException_SIGKILL: 

RAN: /usr/bin/sleep 100

STDOUT:

STDERR:
```

How can I avoid the background thread logging an error for something I expect to happen?

Comment: Have you imported the logging module by any change? Also, have you looked at the docs?

Comment: No, I have not imported the logging module. Yes, I have looked at the docs. The code is from an example in the docs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to catch this exception execute your process with [`_bg_exec=False`](http://amoffat.github.io/sh/sections/special_arguments.html#bg-exc) and execute p.wait().

```
In [21]: p = sh.sleep(100, _bg=True, _bg_exc=False)
    ...: try:
    ...:     p.kill()
    ...:     p.wait()
    ...: except sh.SignalException_SIGKILL as err:
    ...:     print("foo")
    ...:
foo
```